# Python Pandas: Why can't I convert 'Time' to to_datetime? Will not recognize time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Time data looks like this:  Time

```
 20:15:00.0

 20:16:00.0

 20:17:00.0

 20:18:00.0

 20:19:00.0

 20:20:00.0

 20:21:00.0

 20:22:00.0

 20:23:00.0

 20:24:00.0
```

data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTENh.jpg)

---

Python recognizes these as:

```
Date             object

 **Time**            **object**

 Open           float64

 High           float64

 Low            float64

 Last           float64
```

---

I've tried to import data like this:
hour

---

```py
df = pd.read_csv('ES_1min_2012_vwap_va.txt', sep=",", nrows=1000, parse_dates=True);

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

---

```
**ERROR**: 

runfile('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Trading/Main/historical data/Index/ES/Intraday Volatility by VIX.py', wdir='C:/Users/user/Desktop/Trading/Main/historical data/Index/ES')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'Time'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Trading\Main\historical data\Index\ES\Intraday Volatility by VIX.py", line 18, in <module>
    df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], errors='ignore')

  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'Time'
```

---

Solved this error a month ago but completely forgot, pls help

Comment: I'm able to convert the Date to datetime64[ns] succesfully, just time is not working. The file is over 10million lines, so I cannot edit it in excel.

Comment: What does `df.columns` give?

Comment: Hey, the other recommendation worked. Did not see a space in front of the time

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a space in front of ' Time', you can use `skipinitialspace=True`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', nrows=1000, parse_dates=True, skipinitialspace=True)
```

Comment: That worked :) You know I spent a few hours on this last month, got an alternative solution working which i can't remember. This is so much easier :) I don't have enough reputation to upvote you but thank you man

Comment: Hehe glad I could help!

Comment: so that was appending today's date onto the time, so I used  

df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"]).dt.time

--------------------


That gives the right value for time now but time becomes an object, not datetime64[ns]. 

How can I keep it as a datetime dtype?

Comment: Also, do you happen to know how to slice data in the data frame if there's duplicate/repeated index values? (Such as date)

Comment: Why do you want the time in datetime64[ns] format? Also if the date is duplicated you should think of a multi column index to make it uniquely identify a row. Unless you can drop the duplicate rows, which is probably not something you want to do.

Comment: b/c I figured it's going to provide functionality later. Yes, did start looking into a multi -col index, and that's why i'd need to drop the newly added date from the time, no? Other wise i'd have a column for day[originial] and a column for day[today]&time

Comment: Since you already have a date field, Why don’t you combine your date field and time field and create a combined column? That way you won’t have to remove the date from the time field?

Comment: That's how I've done it in excel. Here i would get an object dtype instead of datetime then I have no functionality. Just getting started with python so I want to understand it right

Comment: Why don't you create a combined column like this:
`df['Date_Time'] = df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time']`

`df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'])`

Comment: 1st error: The ' ' string won't let the addition.
2nd error: getting rid of that string, it doesn't want to add timestamp and datetime.time

Comment: `df['Date_Time'] = df['Date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['Time'].astype(str)`

Comment: Thank you, I understand. Did not see astpye funcitonality earlier.